# Evaluating Conditions for Normal Family

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

I am having troubles dealing with following problems:

1. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of all holomorphic functions defined on a region $\Omega$ with values on the right half plane. If there exists a point $z_0 \in \Omega$ such that $f(z_0)=g(z_0)$ for all $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family.
2. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of all holomorphic functions defined on a region $\Omega$ with values in $U_0=\mathbb{C} \backslash \{x+i0, 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$. If there exists a point $z_0 \in \Omega$ such that $f(z_0)=g(z_0)$ for all $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family.

A hint is to use the following version of the Montel Theorem:

*Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$. If every function in $\mathcal{F}$ does not assume the same two values, then $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family.*

However, I don't see any conditions in the above two problems that can imply "*If every function in $\mathcal{F}$ does not assume the same two values*". Any clarifications or hints will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: All functions in $\mathcal{F}$ omit the values in the left half plane.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks! I see how stupid I was now. Somehow I misunderstood "assume the same two values" as "assume a certain value twice".

Comment: It is worth noting that $\forall f,g \in \mathcal{F},  f(z_0)=g(z_0)$ is not redundant. The condition, at least I thought, is used to show that no sequence of $\mathcal{F}$ has a subsequence that is compactly divergent.